# Как в Java распарсить дату с выводом 2-ух значного представления месяца?

Tags: java, парсер, localdate

```
public String parseDate(LocalDate localDate) {
        int year = localDate.getYear();
        int month = localDate.getMonthValue();
        int dayOfMonth = localDate.getDayOfMonth();
        return dayOfMonth + "-" + month + "-" + year;
    }
Вывод: 10-5-2020 
Нужно: 10-05-2020
```

Comment: String.format("%02d-%02d-%04d" , dayOfMonth,month,year)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как вы распарсили значения, то попробуйте так через формат

```
String.format("%02d-%02d-%04d" , dayOfMonth,month,year) 

String.format("%02d-%02d-%04d" , 1,1,2020); // 01-01-2020
```

А хорошо использовать форматер из LocalDate

```
localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"))
```

Comment: Спасибо localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")) - это то, что я искал.

Comment: @Dmitriy можете пометить как полезный ответ